# Can reflection be used to get a concrete implementing type (e.g. Class<? extends MyInterface>)?

Tags: java, reflection

My goal is to reflect all the static classes in a container class and collect them into a map of `simpleName -> class`.

This can be done 'by hand' with no problem, but I'd really like to do it programatically.

For example, given:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doThing();
}
```

And a class containing several classes implementing that interface

```
public class MyStuff {
    public static class One implements MyInterface {...}
    public static class Two implements MyInterface {...}
    public static class Three implements MyInterface {...}
}
```

The following manually created map works A-OK.

```
public void demo(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, Class<? extends MyInterface>> myMap = ImmutableMap.of(
        "One", One.class,
        "Two", Two.class,
        "Three", Three.class,
    )

}
```

And I can use it for useful things such a deserialization with Gson:

```
MyInterface object = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, myMap.get("One"))
```

Now, what I'd like to do is *not* build that map by hand, but instead use reflection to build it.

Ideally, something along the lines of:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends MyInterface>> options = new HashMap<>();
for (Class<?> cls : MyStuff.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
    options.put(cls.getSimpleName(), cls)
}
```

But this doesn't compile, as `getDeclaredClasses` is fixed to `Class<?>`.

Interestingly, Java seems to have all the information it needs during runtime. I can print out each class and see that it is the correct implementing class of `MyInterface`. I feel like I *should* be able to get the types I need. However, I can't figure out how to make that final compile-time hop to get a `Class<? extends MyInterface>`

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Why do you feel that `myMap.get("One")` is better than `One.class`? It more error prone, e.g. to typo's.

Comment: @Andreas It was only for sake of example. The entire thing would be called dynamically rather than me directly accessing the map by hand

Comment: You can use `cls.asSubclass(MyInterface.class)` to cast the `Class` to `Class<? extends MyInterface>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require that the nested class implements `MyInterface`, you should check for that, and once you've done that, you can safely cast the value.

```
private static Map<String, Class<? extends MyInterface>> buildOptions() {
    Map<String, Class<? extends MyInterface>> options = new HashMap<>();
    for (Class<?> cls : MyStuff.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
            options.put(cls.getSimpleName(), cls.asSubclass(MyInterface.class));
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(options); // Make it immutable
}
```

Comment: Nit: if you are going to suppress the warning, declare a local variable in the innermost condition and suppress on that, to avoid accidentally suppressing something else in the method.